# Does Scala Anorm String Replacement Sanitize Inputs?

Tags: sql, scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I am using the Play! framework along with Anorm to access the database. I often see examples like the following where object members are injected into the SQL statement directly.

My question is, are these inputs sanitized? Most examples look like the following:

```
object Person {
    def save(p:Person) {
        DB.withConnection ("default") { implicit connection =>
            SQL("""
                 INSERT INTO person(firstName,lastName)
                 values ({firstName}, {lastName})
                """
               ).on(
                "firstName" -> p.firstName,
                "lastName"  -> p.lastName
            ).executeUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

I will attempt to find out by way of hacking, but it's easy to make a mistake so I thought asking was more appropriate, and I can draw on the wisdom of the crowd.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [its source code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm/Anorm.scala), Anorm builds only[`java.sql.PreparedStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), which prevent such SQL injection. (see the [PreparedStatement wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) page for a general explanation)

Comment: Could you please update your "its source code" link to https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/1384c85434254da8cbd73ac5ba93bf258c04bf12/core/src/main/scala/anorm/SimpleSql.scala#L8-L19?